# FedCM Migration: Google sign-in prompt is not shown again after user closes manually

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-one-tap, fedcm

I'm trying to migrate Google One Tap to FedCM.
But when user closes prompt manuall, prompt doesn't pop up again even the page is refreshed.
As I checked, my site was blocked Third-party sign in prompt (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/14264742)

Is there a way to prevent Google block Third-party Sign in prompt of my site ?